Can part of space be causally disconnected from the rest of the universe by being surrounded by black holes?
Is it possible for black hole event horizons to overlap and form a spherical wall around an island of space (that's not inside a black hole) while still being causally disconnected from the rest of the universe?

More on topology of event horizons.

This question is similar to: A Sphere of Black Holes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

that's a cute question...should be able to a nice scaling check since $r_s = m$ and each covers $\pi r^2$ of a $4\pi R^2$ shell, from which you get $M=R_S < R$.
